# Setting cookie by calling webpage by Microsoft.XMLHTTP

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

The situation:
I have 2 webpages with 2 domains (backoffice.myurl.com & www.myurl.com).
The backoffice is written in classic asp, the frontend in asp.net 3.5 (vb.net)

When I hit a button in the backoffice, I want to set a cookie on the frontend. 
I do this by calling a page on the frontend via Microsoft.XMLHTTP

```
Dim GetConnection
Set GetConnection = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
GetConnection.Open "POST", webserviceLocation, False 
GetConnection.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
GetConnection.Send("data=" &value)
```

In the aspx code I read the posted value and put it in a cookie:

```
If Not Request.Cookies("mytest3") Is Nothing Then

        Response.Cookies("mytest3").Expires = Now.AddYears(-23)
    End If

    Response.Cookies.Set(New HttpCookie("mytest3", Request.Form.Item("data")))
    Response.Cookies("mytest3").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(30)
```

On another page on the frontend I want to read that cookie:

```
Request.Cookies("mytest3").Value
```

but the Request.Cookies("mytest3") is 'nothing' there.
Apparently the cookie is not set. What am I doing wrong or how can I solve this?
The pages are called (my debugger hits the breakpoints)

Is this even possible at all?

Comment: The VBScript code you posted runs on the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the cookie you need to explicitly set the [domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.domain.aspx):

```
' I do not remember if the value should be set to myurl.com or .myurl.com
' Please test
Response.Cookies("mytest3").Domain = "myurl.com"
```

This way the browser will send the cookie along each request to `*.myurl.com`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will probably work but it didn't work in combination with my asp call to the aspx.
I used a totally different approach (I skipped the cookie part) and it works perfectly now. Thnx for thinking

Answer (score 1):

Darin has answered your question but you have another problem with this line:-

```
Response.Cookies("mytest3").Expires = Now.AddYears(-23)
```

The response Cookie collection is a differentc collection to that of the Request collection.  The response cookies is always empty until code specifically adds a cookie to it.  Hence the above line will fail.